# Jenkins how to use AnchorChain plugin to add external URL to Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to link an external URL to Jenkins pipeline. This should be accessible while the build is running. AnchorChain had been suggested in several pages and so trying to use it but the [documentation](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin) is less explanatory for a newbie. I installed the AnchorChain Plugin and added the following in the pipeline script.

```
sh "echo 'File1 http://localhost:8080/api' > anchorChain.tsv"
```

When I start the build, the console output shows

> + echo webAppUrlFile  http://localhost:8181/api

Now I want to add this link to the sidebar of the build job similar to an HTML Publisher report link. What are the next steps?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using tabs as delimiters between:
**name url icon** 
as outlined in this post: [Jenkins_wiki](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/AnchorChain+plugin)

 Note: The icon field is optional. If you don't specify one, you'll get one by default. I was unable to specify one using an http:// address (another problem for another day) so I just omit the field and get the default icon.

In order to get the side-bar link to show up in your Jenkins job, you'll:

1. Install the AnchorChain plugin. Once it's installed (and you've restarted Jenkins),
2. In your Job config (Build Section) in an execute shell, you'll add the output to the AnchorChain.tsv:

   echo "Artifacts ${ARTIFACTS_URL}" > AnchorChain.tsv
3. In your Post Build Actions section, you'll add the Anchor Chain action

   [image: Add Anchor Chain Action to your build job]
4. Add your file reference to the File name field:
   [image: FileName]
5. Try out a build. Result after the build depicted in screenshot below.

   [image: Artifacts]